# User posts answer in response to comment, not the original question

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, accepted-answer, wrong-answers

The original question is very specific and it was answered correctly several times.

However, in the comments section, the OP later then says he wants something totally different than what he originally asked for.  A user then takes that out of comments and posts another "Answer" which has almost nothing to do with the posted "Question".

[Can I make an <input> box have text that wraps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981791/can-i-make-an-input-box-have-text-that-wraps/)

I down-voted the irrelevant answer and then explained the down-vote.  Now the user wants to argue back & forth about how the posted answer is relevant when it clearly is not.

I flagged it for moderation as...

> not an answer
>
> This was posted as an
>   answer, but it does not answer the
>   question. It should possibly be an
>   edit, a comment, another question, or
>   deleted altogether.

Now there's nothing telling me if it's been reviewed yet so I don't know if I was wrong for flagging it and that I should not flag it again.

Will I eventually be notified of a moderator decision?

Is this a gray area or is it as clear cut as I am claiming?

I did not answer the question myself so I don't have an interest in who ultimately gets credit but I do care about maintaining quality at this site.  I believe obvious wrong answers getting accepted should be correctable by a moderator.

Since the answer has not yet been accepted, I'm hoping a moderator will eventually settle it before it's too late.

Thanks!

Comment: I kinda thought flagging a post was fire-and-forget. Maybe you're right, maybe you're wrong, maybe it's a grey area, maybe the moderators are having a day off - whatever happens, your job is done. Beyond that, there would be a risk that some control-freak types may well hang around, harangue the moderators, and try to dictate exactly how things should be handled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see *some* information on your flag in your [Flagging Summary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-weight/594235) (note that while that URL is to *your* flagging summary, I can't see it - a user can only see their own, and I just composed your URL from mine).

- In yellow background/gray text you will see the comment you made on the flag
- Below that, if any moderator action has been taken, it will appear next to a ♦, such as "♦ Post Deleted"

On the right side of the page, you will see a summary of response to your flags:

- How many flags you have left ("5 posts flagged as requiring moderator attention")
- How many flags are still pending (This line will only show up if you have any — e.g. "1 are waiting for review")
- How many were marked valid/how many invalid

In this case, your flag sounds decent, but don't worry if no action was taken.  As long as you are using flagging with good intent (and have a reasonably understanding of the rules), you will inevitably make more good flags than "invalid".

Keep flagging!

P.S. ***Please*** let the OP know not to do this, and **post a new question instead** — since this isn't a forum, it's the right way for future users to potentially benefit from one question, while hopefully starting a completely new Q&A where *more* users can benefit!

Answer (score 5):

Nothing much to see here.

There's a lot of bikeshedding going on, and a bit of confusion as to what the OP is actually asking, but anyone can answer the question any way they want, so long as **it is an actual answer** and not "Thanks," "Me too." "This didn't work for me," "Any idea," or ["I like turtles."](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMNry4PE93Y)

The OP can accept any answer he wants.  They get to control the checkbox, not the community or the mods.  The community can express their approval or disapproval for any given answer by voting.

Don't use "Not an Answer" as a synonym for "I don't like the answer."  That's what downvotes are for.

Comment: What's wrong with turtles!